# Геокодирование google maps api

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api, google-maps, карты

Имею вот такой скрипт геокодирования адресов из базы и их обновления. Пытаюсь отгеокодировать 2500 адресов. Почему то это происходит со скачками, то есть геокодируются 6 адресов потом 6 пропускается и далее все в таком же духе. Может быть кто-нибудь знает решение данной проблемы?

```
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php

$sdb_name = "afanasy.mysql";
$user_name = "afanasy_map";
$user_password = ":k3FmCFb";
$db_name = "afanasy_map";

if(!$link = mysql_connect($sdb_name, $user_name, $user_password))
{
  echo "<br>Не могу соединиться с сервером базы данных<br>";
  exit();
}


if(!mysql_select_db($db_name, $link))
{
  echo "<br>Не могу выбрать базу данных<br>";
  exit();
}

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

$addresses = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM markers') or die('Ошибка при выполнении запроса к таблице markers": '.mysql_error());
    // Общее количество адресов и количество адресов, в обработке которых произошла ошибка
    $countGeocode = $countGeocodeFault = 0;
    // Обработка адресов
    $result = '<table style="width:600px">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($addresses)) {
        $countGeocode++;
        // Обращение к http-геокодеру
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address='.$row["address"].'&sensor=false');
        // Если геокодировать удалось, то записываем в БД
        $status = $xml->status;
        echo $xml;
        if ($status == 'OK') {
            $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
            $lng = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
            $result .= '<tr><td>'.$row['address'].'</td><td>'.$lat.', '.$lng.'</td></tr>';
            mysql_query("UPDATE markers SET lat = '$lat', lng = '$lng' WHERE id = '$row[id]'") or die("Ошибка при обновлении данных в таблице: ".mysql_error());
        } else {
            $result .= '<tr style="color:red"><td>'.$row['address'].'</td><td>ошибка</td></tr>';
            $countGeocodeFault++;
        }
    };
    $result .= '</table>';
    // Вывод результата
    echo $result;
    // Закрытие соеденинения с сервером
    mysql_close($dp);
    // Вывод общего количество прогеокодированных результатов
    if ($countGeocode) {
        echo '<div style="margin-top:1em">Всего обработано адресов: '.$countGeocode.'</div>';
        if ($countGeocodeFault) {
            echo '<div style="color:red">Не удалось прогеокодировать: '.$countGeocodeFault.'</div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div>Таблица с адресами пуста.</div>';
    }
```

Comment: Вероятно, у API Google карт есть лимит - 6 запросов в секунду. Посмотри доку и логируй ответы.

Comment: @MichaelPak Посмотрел, да у google лимит 10 запросов в секунду. Как можно это обойти?

Comment: Никак. Только если реально делать 10 запросов в секунду.

Answer (score 1):

У `API Google maps` стоит ограничение на 10 запросов в секунду. Обойти никак нельзя, просто можно делать `sleep()` через каждые 10 запросов:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($addresses)) {
    // Запрос к API и обновление строк в БД
    if ($i % 10 == 0) sleep(1);
}
```

Для оптимизации процесса, можно посмотреть, сколько по времени идет запрос и обновление строк в бд и уменьшить значение `sleep()`.